# Reason for slow upload time to s3 from lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

We have a service on ec2 and we have a requirement to upload **many** files to s3 bucket but the number of requests is less than maximum configured on s3.When we upload it using the ec2 instance, it uploads each file in almost 200 ms. The same files with same content length is taking more time on AWS lambda. Is there any particular reason for increase in time?
I see increase in time for some files and not for others.Some are taking around 3-4sec for same content length.
The ec2 instance is c5.large and I have configured 10 GB to AWS lambda function.
The bucket is in the same region as the lambda function.This time is obtained from the logs by measuring time before the data is to be uploaded and after upload is complete.These files are made from processing of data from database calls inside the application.

Comment: Where are those files comming from? Does your lambda have to download them first from some other storage, then upload to S3?

Comment: See if it's a cold start issue with lambda here is the related link for the issue and mitigations
https://aithority.com/it-and-devops/cloud/5-ways-to-prevent-aws-lambda-cold-starts/

Comment: @Marcin the data is retrieved from database but there is no difference in the time to retrieve data from database

Comment: How do you know? Maybe your lambda does something differently to access the DB then your instance, e.g. uses different programing language, libraries, etc.

Comment: The same code has been migrated

Comment: Do you log just before the api call and just after or is the logging over the course of several lines of execution? I'd recommend using x-ray to get further information on exactly how long each process is taking

Comment: If it affects some files and not others, I would suspect cold-start times. You don't say what language you're using, but some (such as Java) have long cold-start time while classes are loaded. Which happens on-demand, so it could show a slowdown depending on where your logging occurs.

Comment: Since all invocations of the same Lambda execution environment write to the same logstream, one way to identify this is to see if the times are longer only when handling the first request (for those logs that show multiple requests).

Comment: @Parsifal checked that and it is for first few requests and language used is java.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no good way around cold-start times.

You can use provisioned concurrency, but that means paying for always-on Lambdas, and Java's "load classes only when needed" design means that you'll need to write explicit code to "warm up" the execution environment before the first request comes in.

One thing that might work is to *limit* the number of concurrent Lambdas. If you barrage Lambda with requests, [it will spin up as many execution environments as it can](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html) to process those requests. So you'll pay the cold-start time for each of those new invocation environments.

However, if you use [reserved concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html), you specify the maximum number of concurrent instances. You will pay the cold-start penalty for each of those instances, but then Lambda will attempt to reuse instances and not spin up new ones. It will, however, shut down environments if there aren't any requests (so you're not paying for them, but will incur cold-start times on the next burst).

You can also smooth out bursts by using an SQS queue: add each file to the queue, configure the number of concurrent Lambdas with reserved concurrency, and let them slowly work their way through the queue.

Lastly, if all you're doing is uploading files, it's worth considering a different implementation language, such as Python.